# PC whirring sound, until physically touched (Video included)

Tags: boot, fan

When I turn on my PC, it starts making a whirring sound.

This noise sometimes stops on its own after 15-30 minutes, but sometimes it doesn't until I physically touch it.

Turn up your volume a bit if you need to: [**VIDEO**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0msCQ8YIp9E&feature=youtu.be)

I had my PC without a side panel for a week, and the problem did not occur during this time.

(Yes I am aware it was a bit dusty at the time of recording, but that is no longer the case, and it occurs regardless)

If it helps, I am running Linux Mint 17

### Edit

If I were to reboot my computer after the noise is over, the noise does not come back up. Because of this, I feel like something is "warming up".

Comment: This sounds like a fan issue.  Replace the fan causing the noise.

Comment: As Ramhound says. What else could possibly be whirring?

Comment: I've heard some old hard drives make a similar noise, but they don't clear up when you bump the case.  Regarding the "warm up" phenomenon, once an out-of-balance condition causes wear, the fan blades aren't confined to spin on a precise axis.  It may settle on the "sweet spot" because that is the most energy-efficient, and once it's spinning, bumping the case can help it do that.  The wear has already happened, though, so it will only get worse over time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things I noticed:

1. The little figurine sitting on top of the case may be causing sound from vibrations.
2. With the PC sitting on the floor, it may need a good cleaning. It is possible fan has dirt stuck to the blades. This can cause the fan to spin off balance causing vibration and premature bearing failure.

I know you said you cleaned it, but should pay special attention to the fan(s) and use a small brush to break loose an caked on dirt from the blades. If that was done and sound is still an issue, replace the fan. Either way, the cleaning won't hurt.

Comment: So clear answer, NOTICE: TuxForLife avoid to buy low quality fans or power supplies or that sounds will be guarantized.

Comment: A corollary: Do periodic cleaning as a prophylactic measure.  Once the dirt results in wear, the damage is done.